# Inferred List Type with Either and Option

Tags: scala

In Scala 2.11.6, putting an `Either` and an `Option` into a List results in the inferred type, `List[Object]`:

```
scala> val e: Either[String, Int] = Right(100)
e: Either[String,Int] = Right(100)

scala> val o: Option[Int] = None
o: Option[Int] = None

scala> List(e, o)
res0: List[Object] = List(Right(100), None)
```

`Either` and `Option` both extend `AnyRef`, so why isn't it a `List[AnyRef]`?

Why doesn't `AnyRef` show up as the Least Upper Bound?

Also, I was expecting a `List[Any]`. Why does `List[Object]` show up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If Scala is used in the context of a Java runtime environment, then
>   scala.AnyRef corresponds to java.lang.Object.

```
scala> val x: List[AnyRef] = List(e, o)
x: List[AnyRef] = List(Right(100), None)
scala> val x: List[java.lang.Object] = List(e, o)
x: List[Object] = List(Right(100), None)
```

You expected the Least Upper Bound `AnyRef` and you got it.
The source of [quote and diagram](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/128).

Answer (score 2):

It is a list of `AnyRef`. `AnyRef` corresponds to `java.lang.Object`. From [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/128):

> If Scala is used in the context of a Java runtime environment, then scala.AnyRef corresponds to java.lang.Object.

You can show just as much with reflection:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> lub(List(typeOf[Either[String, Int]], typeOf[Option[Int]]))
res43: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Object

scala> typeOf[AnyRef] =:= typeOf[java.lang.Object]
res44: Boolean = true

scala> typeOf[AnyRef] =:= typeOf[Any]
res45: Boolean = false
```